# Calling consecutive java tasks in a shell script

Tags: java, command-line, ant, task

This may be a rudimentary question but the answer was not readily available.

I'd like to create a shell script that calls 3 tasks consecutively, but wait till the previous task is complete.

Like so:

a. call first Java program via ant
b. call third party Java application 
c. call third Java program via ant

I'm wondering if there is a way to check and ensure a. is done before b. is called and same for b. and c.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

By default ant tasks happen in the foreground, so your script won't continue until each ant task has finished. You only need to mess with things if you want the opposite behavior: all three tasks happening simultaneously

Comment: Thanks Micheal, I'll try and report back.

Answer (score 0):

```
java some.package

if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then exit -1; fi;

java some.other.package
```

By default calls inside the script are consecutive.
If the first java execution 'some.package' doesn't return 0, the normal exit code, the script will exit with -1 without executing 'some.other.package'

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are working in a *nix shell, an easy solution that comes to mind would be to just sequentially execute all three commands with the && operator:

```
#!/bin/sh
ant task -f build.xml && java org.mycompany.app && ant anothertask -f buld2.xml
```

The && operator makes

> [...] each command execute in turn, provided that the previous command has given a return value of true (zero). At the first false (non-zero) return, the command chain terminates (the first command returning false is the last one to execute [1](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/list-cons.html#LISTCONSREF)).